# Calculated read-only properties

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to implement properties on objects which values are derived from values of properties from other objects. For example, a property named TotalPoints in a class named Student has the following code in get{},

```
foreach(var subject in Subjects)
{
  _totalPoints += subject.Points;
}

return _totalPoints;
```

This works for simple case. However, when there are more levels involved, e.g., Subject.Points is actually refers to something else. The calculation will be slower. What I am trying to figure out is the following:

- If there is any way to detect if there is any changes in value in Points, if not, I do not want to recalculate _totalPoints;
- Is there any alternative way to implement this? What I am thinking is also if it is possible to "inform" TotalPoints that one of the Subject.Points' value has changed, so TotalPoints needs to be re-calculated.

Appreciate if anyone has any idea. Thanks.

Comment: The classic way of doing this would be to have your types implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and the type that holds them should subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of each of it's properties, calculating the `TotalPoints` value when the `Points` property is changed - However, that would add complexity to your code, and unless the calculation is really slow (that is, humanly noticeable) I would think twice before preferring this over the simpler code you now have.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is an event driven system (see [dot net events](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/events/)). Here's a simple example:

```
public class PointsProvider
{
    public event Action<int> OnPointsChanged;
    private int points;
    public int Points
    {
        get => points;
        set
        {
            if (points == value)
                return;
            int oldValue = points;
            points = value;
            OnPointsChanged?.Invoke(points - oldValue);
        }
    }
}

public class TotalPointsProvider
{
    private PointsProvider providerA, providerB;

    private int totalPoints;
    public int TotalPoints => totalPoints;

    public TotalPointsProvider()
    {
        providerA = new PointsProvider();
        providerA.OnPointsChanged += UpdateTotalPoints;
        providerB = new PointsProvider();
        providerB.OnPointsChanged += UpdateTotalPoints;

        totalPoints = providerA.Points + providerB.Points;
    }

    private void UpdateTotalPoints(int delta)
    {
        totalPoints += delta;
    }
}
```

`TotalPointsProvider` gets notified, once one of it's `PointsProvider`s changes and updates it's own value.

If you have lot's of changes in your sub system (`PointsProvider`) but request the result unfrequently you might want to build a lazy system:

```
public class PointsProvider
{
    public event Action OnPointsChanged;
    private int points;
    public int Points
    {
        get => points;
        set
        {
            if (points == value)
                return;
            points = value;
            OnPointsChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

public class TotalPointsProvider
{
    private PointsProvider providerA, providerB;

    private bool dirty = true;

    private int totalPoints;
    public int TotalPoints
    {
        get
        {
            if (dirty)
            {
                totalPoints = providerA.Points + providerB.Points;
                dirty = false;
            }
            return totalPoints;
        }
    }

    public TotalPointsProvider()
    {
        providerA = new PointsProvider();
        providerA.OnPointsChanged += RecalculationNecessary;
        providerB = new PointsProvider();
        providerB.OnPointsChanged += RecalculationNecessary;
    }

    private void RecalculationNecessary()
    {
        dirty = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going with your own implementation instead of `INotifyPropertChanged` you might as well send the difference between the old value and the new value to the listener, so that instead of recalculating the entire thing the calculation would be simply to add that difference (note, difference might be positive or negative). Otherwise you're just moving the bottle neck around from the getter to setter of the `TotalPoints` property...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know. I just wanted to sketch out the direction in which to go. Depending on the scenario a direct value update might not even be the most performant solution.

Comment: Well, the lazy version is better, so +1

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the reply. The second example that you have provided does give me some ideas. I think this seems to the simplest possible way.

Answer (score -1):

```
get
    {
        return _totalPoints;
    }
set
    {
        foreach(var subject in Subjects)
         {
        _totalPoints += subject.Points;
         }
    }
```

Comment: code-only answers are frowned upon here. Try adding some explanation!